# Color box with rounded corners around a fragment of a formula

Tags: math-mode, boxes, highlighting, backgrounds, rounded-corners

Is there any way in TeX to highlight some part of a formula with a box having colored background and rounded corners?

At present, I need to export such formulas into an image, add those highlight boxes in GIMP, and import back into the document as an image. But this is a mess, and I need to redo all of that every time I change anything in these formulas :/ So it'd be better if I could mark up those fragments of my formulas in LaTeX natively. Is it possible?

I saw one example of boxes made with TikZ package, but I couldn't figure out how does it work and how to assimilate it into my own document. I don't want to make floating boxes inside a document, but just around a fragment of a formula to highlight it. (No, I cannot use text colors for that, because this text already has some colors which means something else, so I need to use background color instead.)

**Edit 1**
Here's the effect I'd like to achieve:

[image: http://sasq.comyr.com/Stuff/WaveFunc1D_pE_my.png]

**Edit 2**
OK, after suggestions from A.Ellet below, I came out with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{My}{RGB}{0,31,63}
\definecolor{MyConst}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{MyFunc}{RGB}{0,75,107}
\definecolor{MyIndep}{RGB}{127,55,0}
\definecolor{MySubst}{RGB}{250,230,230}
\newcommand{\const}[1]{{\color{MyConst}\mathrm{#1}}}     % normal constant
\newcommand{\uconst}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}                     % universal mathematical constant
\newcommand{\var}[1]{{\color{MyIndep}#1}}                % independent variable
\newcommand{\subst}[1]{{\colorbox{MySubst}#1}}           % substitution

\begin{document}
$$\color{My}
{\color{MyFunc}\Psi} =
\const{\Psi_{_0}}\;
\uconst{e}^{\uconst{i} \left(
    \colorbox{MySubst!50}{
        \frac{p}{\const{\hbar}}
    }   % line 24
    \var{x} - \frac{E}{\const{\hbar}}\var{t} \right) }
$$
\end{document}
```

which doesn't work. It throws errors like:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.24    }
```

(I marked the line 24 with a comment.)
When I remove the `\frac` from inside the box and replace it by just `x`, it starts to work, but apparently from the formatting it seems to treat is as plain text instead of math.

**Edit 3**  Here's your code editted to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{My}{RGB}{0,31,63}
\definecolor{MyConst}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{MyFunc}{RGB}{0,75,107}
\definecolor{MyIndep}{RGB}{127,55,0}
\definecolor{MySubst}{RGB}{250,230,230}
\newcommand{\const}[1]{{\color{MyConst}\mathrm{#1}}}     % normal constant
\newcommand{\uconst}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}                     % universal mathematical constant
\newcommand{\var}[1]{{\color{MyIndep}#1}}                % independent variable
\newcommand{\subst}[1]{\colorbox{MySubst}{#1}}           % substitution

\begin{document}
\[
\color{My}{\color{MyFunc}}\Psi =
\const{\Psi_{_0}}\;
\uconst{e}^{
        \uconst{i} 
        \left(
            \colorbox{MySubst!50}{$\frac{p}{\const{\hbar}}$}
            \var{x} - \frac{E}{\const{\hbar}}
            \var{t} 
        \right) 
    }
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you checked out `fancybox`?

Comment: I've just tried, but it creates ugly frame with fake shadow, no background, and no rounded corners, and I don't know how to control its appearance to fit it to my needs. Is there any documentation for this package? Could these boxes be parametrized? (colors, rounded corners, backgrounds, turn off fake shadows etc.)

Comment: I think you can have a look to the [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) package because it's specifically designed for your need. An exhaustive example on the site is [\boxed{}, TikZ and colored equation background](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75129/boxed-tikz-and-colored-equation-background).

Comment: I believe you should better post a picture of the desired output. Without that, your intentions are not entirely clear.

Comment: @A.Ellett: `tcolorbox` and `hf-tikz` are both in TeXLive and MikTeX.

Comment: @tohecz: I added a picture of what I'd like to get in my question, and a sample of code using `fancybox` which doesn't work.

Comment: First, you should use `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`.  The later is deprecated in `LaTeX`.  Also, if you used some indentation, your code would be a little bit more readable.  I've edited your code.  The error was that you didn't switch back into mathmode within the `\colorbox` command.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino. My version of TeXLive is from 2011.  I guess I have to update it (Yikes!  That always scares me:  what am I going to break?)

Comment: @A.Ellett: oh, I remembered that no problems occurred to me with the upgrade (under Unix). You're missing a lot of nice packages now `;)`

Answer (score 16):

A solution with [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) (requires two compilation runs):

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\definecolor{My}{RGB}{0,31,63}
\definecolor{MyConst}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{MyFunc}{RGB}{0,75,107}
\definecolor{MyIndep}{RGB}{127,55,0}
\definecolor{MySubst}{RGB}{250,230,230}
\newcommand{\const}[1]{{\color{MyConst}\mathrm{#1}}}     % normal constant
\newcommand{\uconst}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}                     % universal mathematical constant
\newcommand{\var}[1]{{\color{MyIndep}#1}}                % independent variable
\newcommand{\subst}[1]{{\colorbox{MySubst}#1}}           % substitution

\hfsetfillcolor{Lavender!50}
\hfsetbordercolor{white}

\begin{document}
\[
\color{My}
{\color{MyFunc}\Psi} =
\const{\Psi_{_0}}\;
\uconst{e}^{\uconst{i} \left(   
    \tikzmarkin{a}(0.01,-0.175)(-0.015,0.3)\frac{p}{\const{\hbar}}\tikzmarkend{a}
    \var{x} - \tikzmarkin{b}(0.01,-0.175)(-0.015,0.3)\frac{E}{\const{\hbar}}\tikzmarkend{b}\var{t} \right) }
\]
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Remarks:

1. it is better to use `\[ \]` rather than `$$ $$`;
2. the package allows you *to not set* in math mode the text inside a `\colorbox`: one just have to declare where the delimiters of the box should be positioned.

From version 0.3 of the package, things are a bit more user-friendly as shown in [hf-tikz doesn't box around equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98540/hf-tikz-doesnt-box-around-equation#101038). The above code can be written thanks to styles as:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\definecolor{My}{RGB}{0,31,63}
\definecolor{MyConst}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{MyFunc}{RGB}{0,75,107}
\definecolor{MyIndep}{RGB}{127,55,0}
\definecolor{MySubst}{RGB}{250,230,230}
\newcommand{\const}[1]{{\color{MyConst}\mathrm{#1}}}     % normal constant
\newcommand{\uconst}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}                     % universal mathematical constant
\newcommand{\var}[1]{{\color{MyIndep}#1}}                % independent variable
\newcommand{\subst}[1]{{\colorbox{MySubst}#1}}           % substitution

% available from version 0.3
\tikzset{offset def/.style={
    above left offset={-0.015,0.3},
    below right offset={0.01,-0.175},
  },
  hl/.style={
    offset def,
    set fill color=Lavender!50,
    set border color=white,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\[
\color{My}
{\color{MyFunc}\Psi} =
\const{\Psi_{_0}}\;
\uconst{e}^{\uconst{i} \left(   
    \tikzmarkin[hl]{a}\frac{p}{\const{\hbar}}\tikzmarkend{a}
    \var{x} - \tikzmarkin[hl]{b}\frac{E}{\const{\hbar}}\tikzmarkend{b}\var{t} \right) }
\]
\end{document}
```

> **Procedure to get .png output**

After reading the comments below, here is a way to get a `.png`. The [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class here really helps since it has a `png` class option.

Save as `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,png, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\definecolor{My}{RGB}{0,31,63}
\definecolor{MyConst}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{MyFunc}{RGB}{0,75,107}
\definecolor{MyIndep}{RGB}{127,55,0}
\definecolor{MySubst}{RGB}{250,230,230}
\newcommand{\const}[1]{{\color{MyConst}\mathrm{#1}}}     % normal constant
\newcommand{\uconst}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}                     % universal mathematical constant
\newcommand{\var}[1]{{\color{MyIndep}#1}}                % independent variable
\newcommand{\subst}[1]{{\colorbox{MySubst}#1}}           % substitution

\hfsetfillcolor{Lavender!50}
\hfsetbordercolor{white}

\begin{document}
$
\color{My}
{\color{MyFunc}\Psi} =
\const{\Psi_{_0}}\;
\uconst{e}^{\uconst{i} \left(   
    \tikzmarkin{a}(0.01,-0.175)(-0.015,0.3)\frac{p}{\const{\hbar}}\tikzmarkend{a}
    \var{x} - \tikzmarkin{b}(0.01,-0.175)(-0.015,0.3)\frac{E}{\const{\hbar}}\tikzmarkend{b}\var{t} \right) }
$
\end{document}
```

and compile with:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
```

This will create

1. test.pdf
2. test.png

perfectly cropped.

Comment: This looks closest to what I want to achieve. But I don't understand your code at all (what does all those numbers mean?). And it doesn't work with my `texlive` installation because of missing `hf-tikz.sty` file (I don't know how to install it correctly under Gentoo without breaking anything in my package manager when messing with the files by hand).

Comment: I just wanted to add some boxy backgrounds, and now I have so many different options to choose, most of them not working at all, and some of them needing fiddling with my installation :-( The code to get it is a mess, I don't understand any single bit of it, and I cannot find any documentation on the Tikz's project page. All of this overwhelms me :-/ and seem to be lot more work than what I was doing so far with re-editing images of those formulas in GIMP, instead of simplifying things. So I'll probably be forced to revert to my old approach :-/ But thanks for all your help anyway.

Comment: @SasQ: the package is quite recent (6 months), so it needs TeXLive 2012. The numbers simply represent the coordinates of the below right and above left corner of the box. If you visit http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/hf-tikz you will find the documentation of the package in a pdf file. Unfortunately I don't know Gentoo, so I don't know how help you in updating the distribution or simply to install a single package.

Comment: I tried to add those files to a subdir into my texlive installation (`/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex`) but it still doesn't see them. Do I need to edit some config files to let LaTeX know about them?

Comment: As to the coordinates: This sounds very hacky anyway, because whenever I'll update something in the formula, I'll be required to update those coords I guess, which is not much an advantage over editting the image in GIMP anyway. Better solution would just mark which block of text needs to be surrounded by the box and update the size of the box automatically when I edit its content.

Comment: OK, I figured out how to install those packages. It required to run `texhash` afterwards. It compiles your code sample without errors, but then in the DVI file all those boxes are offset in wrong places, and they're not antialiased :-/ And when I try to convert them to PNG image (which I ultimately need), the boxes disappear completely. WHAT A MESS! ;-/

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino.  I just completed my TexLive 2012 update for Mac.  I've now got `tcolorbox` but `hf-tikz` is not part of the installation for Macs yet.  Can you point me to a link of how to install it to my local `texmf` directory in a manner that will be found by `LaTeX`?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino.  Found what I want at [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1041/22413].

Comment: @A.Ellett: notice that when you install MacTeX (thus TeXLive) 2012 you have a distribution that more or less contains the packages and their version in July; from that point on, lots of packages have been updated and new have come, like hf-tikz which the first release was dated August. You just need to go in Applications->TeX->TexUtility (now I don't remember the exact name) and update your package list. `:)`

Comment: @SasQ: please, notice that with the package you really don't need png conversion or stuff like that; moreover, since it is based on the `\tikzmark` macro, it is not true that you have to update the coordinates each time: my answer clearly demonstrates that the same coordinates are used twice even if the second term is wider; if you read the documentation you will discover that the coordinates represent just amount of space the box have been _extended_ from the default values (concept of _extensible markers_).

Comment: Yes I *do* need PNG conversion, because this is supposed to be my target output format. I use TeX as a kind-of compiler of equation images from plain-text source codes. I export to DVI first, and then I use `dvipng` to quickly convert it to an image with a desired DPI resolution. And it worked quite well for simpler formulas. But I stucked on those highlight boxes with round corners. Your method with `hf-tikz` appears to work, but when I export to DVI, I see those boxes offset out of their places. In PDF they seem OK (strange). And when I convert DVI->PNG, they disappear at all. VERY strange!

Comment: Sorry, perhaps is my fault, but I don't remember that you specifically asked for having a `.png` output. Of course, there's a method, without using GIMP, to directly have a .png compiling with pdflatex.

Comment: @SasQ: please see my update. This procedure will create you a `.png` without a DVI conversion that will fail (and is not strange, but normal behaviour - you probably compiled with `latex` and not `pdflatex`).

Answer (score 13):

Use `fancybox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    x^2 + y^2 &= 4
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   \fbox{$ x^2 + y^2$} &= 4
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   \colorbox{blue!20}{$ x^2 + y^2$} &= 4
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   \ovalbox{$ x^2 + y^2$} &= 4
\end{align}


\begin{align}
   \ovalbox{$\displaystyle{} \frac{x+2}{x^2+y^2} $} &= 4
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice how I have to re-enter math mode within the various framing boxes.  Also for the fraction, I had to declare `\displaystyle` inside the box to get the fraction to be formatted appropriately for an `align` environment.

Comment: OK, the last one seems quite similar to what I need to achieve. It just lacks the last feature: rounded corners.

Comment: But from some strange reasons, it doesn't work with my LaTeX framework (LiveTex on Gentoo). It says that it cannot recognize my defined color (! LaTeX Error: Undefined color `MySubst!20'). This color is defined and it works for other things.

Comment: Please post a MWE above so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Another problem: It seems to forget that it's in a math mode, because fonts are big and not italic for variables. Also, I cannot use \frac inside of it, because it throws parse errors concerning unpaired braces. Strange...

Comment: Please note the changes I've made above

Comment: OK, I see your changes. Re-entering the math mode solved this parsing problem for `\frac`. Now I have this box with pink background under my fraction. Closer to what I need. Now what's left is: rounded corners (not for frame, as with your `ovalbox` examples above, though it'd be probably good to have both background and frame formatting options together in future projects) and paddings/margins (now it seems a bit too crowded for me).

Comment: @A.Ellett; Is this possible to change the rule color of `\ovalbox`?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `mdframed` package and define your own style in preamble

```
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrameYellow}{%
    linecolor=red,
    outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin=20pt,
    innerleftmargin=20pt,
    backgroundcolor=yellow!50!white}
```

Then you can include your formula like that

```
\begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrameYellow]
\begin{align*}
N_1=&NP_1=N\dfrac{e^{-\beta\epsilon}}{e^{-\beta\epsilon} + 2e^{-2\beta\epsilon}     + 3e^{-3\beta\epsilon}+ 4e^{-4\beta\epsilon}}= N \dfrac{1}{1 + 2e^{-    \beta\epsilon} + 3e^{-2\beta\epsilon}+ 4e^{-3\beta\epsilon}}\\
N_2=&NP_2=N\dfrac{2e^{-2\beta\epsilon}}{e^{-\beta\epsilon} +     2e^{-2\beta\epsilon} + 3e^{-3\beta\epsilon}+ 4e^{-4\beta\epsilon}}= N \dfrac{1}    {1 + \frac12 e^{+\beta\epsilon} + \frac32 e^{-\beta\epsilon}+     2e^{-2\beta\epsilon}}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
N_3=&NP_3=N\dfrac{3e^{-3\beta\epsilon}}{e^{-\beta\epsilon} +     2e^{-2\beta\epsilon} + 3e^{-3\beta\epsilon}+ 4e^{-4\beta\epsilon}}=N \dfrac{1}{1     + \frac13e^{+2\beta\epsilon} + \frac23e^{+\beta\epsilon}+ \frac43e^{-    \beta\epsilon}}\\
N_4=&NP_4=N\dfrac{4e^{-4\beta\epsilon}}{e^{-\beta\epsilon} +     2e^{-2\beta\epsilon} + 3e^{-3\beta\epsilon}+ 4e^{-4\beta\epsilon}}= N \dfrac{1}    {1 + \frac14e^{+3\beta\epsilon} + \frac12e^{-2\beta\epsilon}+     \frac34e^{+\beta\epsilon}}
\end{align*}
\end{mdframed}
```

The result is something like that

[image]

[image]

The nice thing with `mdframed` is that it can split over pages!

Comment: This is a nice package, but it doesn't seem to work inside another math environment.

Comment: @A.Ellett: You are right...I've just seen the edited question...

Comment: It also doesn't seem to work for my installation (`texlive` on Gentoo). It says that the package couldn't be found (`! LaTeX Error: File `mdframed.sty' not found`), and for now I don't know how to install it. Although I'm not a noob in the LaTeX syntax, I'm a complete noob in the maintaining own installation, packages & use those extensions in my code. I couldn't find any good documentations for the packages you're describing here.

Comment: @SasQ: You can download the package manually from ctan http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed You can extract it, in your latex folder(where all packages' sty are) or just extract in the same folder as your .tex file. Note that you will also need to install the `l3packages` as well http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages

Comment: I added those files from CTAN to my installation in a subdir, but LaTeX still doesn't see them. Do I need also to edit some config files?

Comment: @SasQ: You don't have to configure anything... Do you get an error while trying to build? You may need to install `l3kernel` and you also need to have in same directory as `mdframed.sty` the relevant `.mdf` files(i.e. md-frame-0.mdf). Try also to copy .sty and .mdf's in the same directory as your .tex file.

Comment: I didn't have to configure, but I did have to run `texhash` command to rehash the packages database.

Comment: @SasQ: I believe that `texhash` is a way to update your packages, right? If so, it doesn't seem weird to me!:) Have you managed to make it run, in the end?