# Adjusting perimeter of colorbox to fit text

Tags: adjustbox, parbox, colorbox

Consider this MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=3.2cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setstretch{1.3}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0.4cm} % sets the perimeter around \colorbox
\newcommand{\titleText}{My really really long title goes here}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\setstretch{2.3}
\noindent \colorbox{black}{\parbox{0.95\linewidth}{\raggedright\textcolor{white}{\Huge \expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\titleText}}}}
\endgroup

\vspace*{2cm}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

How can I adjust the perimeter of the `colorbox` to 'wrap' around the text like this? I'd still like all the same functionality of automatic line breaks etc.

[image]

## UPDATE

I tried using `soul` but that ran into issues with `\textcolor{white}`. Based on the recommendation from this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48549/187447) I tried using `ulem`. But still I can't get a black polygon to wrap around text. Any ideas?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=3.2cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setstretch{1.3}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0.4cm} % sets the perimeter around \colorbox
\newcommand{\titleText}{My really really long title goes here}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % use normalem to protect \emph
\newcommand\hl{\bgroup\markoverwith
    {\textcolor{black}{\rule[-6.5ex]{100pt}{14.5ex}}}\ULon}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\setstretch{2.3}
\noindent \hl{\parbox{0.95\linewidth}{\raggedright\textcolor{white}{\Huge \expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\titleText}}}}
\endgroup

\vspace*{2cm}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm note sure colorbox can do that, or any of the other box constructions, they are called box and not polygon for a reason. It might be that some of the highlight features of `ulem` might be useful.

Comment: ... or with highlight from soul, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5980/121799.

Comment: @marmot Do you think a TikZ node is a possibility?

Comment: Probably but it won't be trivial because to Ti*k*Z node does not know by default where the text ends. What is wrong with `soul`?

Comment: @marmot Just tried using `soul`. However, it won't let me use `textcolor{white}` - something to do with this I think - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48501/soul-broken-highlighting-with-xcolor-when-using-selectcolormodel

Comment: If I add `\usepackage{soul}` and add `\sethlcolor{black}
\begingroup\lineskip -2pt
\noindent\textcolor{white}{\Huge\MakeUppercase{\hl{\titleText}}}
\endgroup` then I get something that looks good except for a small gap which I thought to cure with `\lineskip -2pt` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @marmot @daleif I have tried using `ulem`, added an update to my question.

Comment: @marmot Thanks! That looks good, but yeah there is a small gap between the lines. Is there a way to increase the 'margin' around the text?

Comment: I added what I know as an answer which I will be happy to remove.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer (because there is a small gap) but to show that I do not experience the problems with `soul` you are describing.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=3.2cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{soul}
\setstretch{1.3}
\newcommand{\titleText}{My really really long title goes here}

\begin{document}
\sethlcolor{black}
\begingroup\lineskip -2pt
\noindent\textcolor{white}{\Huge\MakeUppercase{\hl{\titleText}}}
\endgroup

\vspace*{2cm}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

if I add (from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282404/121799))

```
\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
    \setul{\dp\strutbox}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox\relax}%
    \let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
    \SOUL@stpreamble
}
\makeatother
```

I get

[image]

Comment: Nice work. I wonder.. if you can adjust the height can you also adjust the width? Cause at the moment the width of the black polygon is too narrow around the edges of the text.

Comment: @Mike I don't. Maybe [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95025/121799) works for you.

Comment: Would this TikZ solution be a feasible option do you think? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88977/putting-a-coloured-background-behind-text-without-adding-whitespace