# Minimal XeTeX distribution for Linux

Tags: xetex, texlive, distributions

I want to run a XeLaTeX instance in Amazon Lambda (Linux). I need the binaries to be less than 200MB. What I need to achieve:

- Create a text-based pdf file out o
- Use many languages as available, including Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Arabic.
- Use custom OTF fonts (e.g. Adobe Garamond Pro).
- Portable, if possible.

No need for math formulas, diagrams, graphics, documentation, source files.

How can I get the size of the binaries as small as possible? I tried the TeXLive distribution, but the "small scheme" that includes XeTeX it is 441MB, way over my limit.

Comment: How many fonts? My (2016) TeX Live seems to have about 2.2 GB in the `doc` folder, 1.9 GB in the `fonts` folder,  and 307 MB in the `tex` folder (of which 161 MB is in `tex/latex`). XeTeX is also the biggest binary on my system (23.5 MB), and what about other programs?  To do it all in under 200MB is going to take some real work....

Comment: According to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/portable-minimal-distribution "MikTeX basic" used to be 157 MB, but I wouldn't bet my own money that you can add everything you want (or need) and stay under 200 MB.

Comment: Maybe install the small scheme on your PC and set up a test document and then deinstall package after package.

Comment: I believe that the reason CJK fonts are not included in the full scheme by default is that they are huge. The directory containing Noto fonts on my system (truetype fonts for a wide variety of languages, including CJK) is 145M. You can't exclude maths fonts and support for formulae. Note that XeTeX also requires a second binary i.e. it is a two stage compilation, in effect, which is why you can specify different options. It is also somewhat tricky, as I understand it, to use non-TeX fonts with XeTeX as opposed to XeLaTeX. If you mean LaTeX, Polyglossia and `fontspec`, too, ....

Comment: What do you mean by `portable`?

Comment: See perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119759/why-cant-tex-lives-size-be-reduced/270103#270103 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267765/how-much-is-the-the-size-of-a-minimal-tex-live-installation (which I guess needs an answer: will sort)

Comment: Note that the macro layer is pretty small: people worry about _e.g._ TikZ but in disk use size it's tiny. Your problem, as others note, will be fonts.

Comment: if using xetex you have the possibility of deleting the entire tex font tree which will massively cut down your tex installation, just use the sytem opentype fonts that you will have already as part of the operating system setup. and you only need xetex and xdvipdfmx bianries