# How to generate a list of all dependencies for a given LaTeX document?

Tags: texlive

I have a couple of relatively complicated multilingual LaTeX documents, I need to work with on several different Linux machines, and in collaboration with various people. The complexity has the side effect, that a huge number of different LaTeX (TeXLive) packages has to be installed in order to compile the respectiv document.

This leads to the problem, that whenever a new player joins the group, who has to fiddle with one of the files, I need to tell him, which dependencies the given LaTeX file has, to make him able to install the needed packages, and to compile the file respectivly.

This is relatively uncomfortable, as it is complicated for me to keep track of the dependencies and not everyone has the capacities to install a broad range of packages (without actually needing them for the given task).

This brings me to my question: Is there a way, to put out a list of needed packages in a human readable format and, ideally to translate this list programmatically in a list of distribution packages? Preferable a command line, which puts out such a list.

Comment: What about using an online service like [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/)?

Comment: @Werner I thought of that, but this has to many disadvantages in our case: The necessity to be online all the time, the problem of data security etc. So unfortunately not an option for us.

Comment: My question seems to overlap with that one:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291317

Comment: You can run LaTeX with the `-recorder` option.  This will generate a file with the extension `.fls` which contains the names of all opened files.

Comment: `snapshot` and `bundledoc`? (Overkill, maybe, as you don't ask about versions.) `\listfiles`?