# What size should MacTex be? I'm trying to download it and it's huge!

Tags: lyx, mactex, file-size

I'm totally new to LaTeX and similar programs. I'm actually trying to get started with LyX as I want something easy to use and basic.

I'm trying to download the MacTeX 'distribution' (I think that's the name for it), but it requires 4.33GB! This seems very large. Is this the correct size for the distribution, or can I find something smaller elsewhere?

Comment: I guess that you can install a basic version, not the complete scheme.

Comment: Thanks Sigur. Is 4.33GB the correct size for the file, then?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: For the complete scheme, yes. With it you will have all the packages to use.

Comment: Sigur - I have a further question (not sure if I need to start a new thread for this, but here goes...). I'm being asked to install something to enable 'cc command' - do you know if this is essential?

Comment: I only know `cc` as a C compiler, but I would imagine the binaries are pre-built in MacTeX.  I suggest you take a screenshot and ask a new question along the lines of 'what's this'. As for the size, full-on TeX distributions are pretty large.  Most everything in there is optional, but (mostly) all of it is useful.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/974 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119759.

Comment: It's huge in part because a full TeX installation provides the means to typeset in virtually all languages, which requires a huge number of font-related files for a large number of alphabets.  Then, there is all the documentation related to all this....

Comment: @nathanglass The message you are getting is normal because you don't have certain commandline tools installed.  The link should have taken you to the right place, but if not, go to the App Store and install XCode.  It's a free download.

Answer (score 0):

The `MacTeX.pkg` file available at `http://tug.org/mactex/downloading.html` is 2.3GB. It will expand to much larger than that. 4.33GB is probably right.

Once you've installed, you can use the TeX Live Utility to update the system, or add new packages.

If you want something smaller, you can look at BasicTeX: http://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html

You can install BasicTeX with the TeX Live Utility to customize your system to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

According to tug.org (the website of the Tex User Group) the package should approximately be 2.3GB

You could consider downloading BasicTex, a stripped down version of MacTex (~90 MB), and add packages you need using the Tex Live manager which is included.

Regards,

Ernst Jan

source and more info and download links: [tug.org](http://www.tug.org/mactex/)

Comment: For use with LyX, this is *not* recommended.

Comment: @AlanMunn Although not recommended it might be worth considering when on a slow or unstable internet connection. Therefore I did mention it. It is also suggested on the Lyx Wiki:
http://wiki.lyx.org/Mac/Mac#Prerequisite