# Do I need to download packages manually for MacTeX and ProTeXt distributions?

Tags: distributions

Do I need to download packages manually for MacTeX and ProTeXt?

on TeXLive Almost all packages are downloaded not as MiKTeX, But What about ProTeXt & MacTeX?

Comment: Both include latex package managers so use those. Nowadays there is not much need to install packages manually. MacTeX (which is just TeXLive packaged for Mac) has two managers (one is just a more Mac like front end for the other). ProTeXt is just miktex + extra, so use the miktex package manager (the miktex console)

Comment: @daleif on TeXLive Almost all packages are downloaded not as MiKTeX, So What about ProTeXt & MacTeX

Comment: The current MacTeX does not include the GUI TeX Live Utility app, due to licensing restrictions, but a link at http://www.tug.org/mactex/index.html takes you to the download site for the app.

Comment: As I said `ProTeXt` is just `MikTeX`, I don't know if they put extra settings on it, haven't installed ProTeXt in 10+ years. MacTeX = TeXLive and will install the same packages. Just note that MacTeX is a snapshot in time, so after installing MacTeX you will need to update it to get the latest updates. A straight TeXLive installes from the currenctly updated packages.

Comment: @murray where do you see info about that licensing restriction?

Comment: @daleif See https://www.tug.org/mactex/whatsinthepackage.html. It's not licensing really,  but Apple's insistence that all apps be signed with an Apple developer id.

Comment: @AlanMunn ahh, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MacTeX *is* TeXLive, but packaged into a single installer for the Mac. By default it installs a full TeXLive distribution, in which case, no, you shouldn't have to install any packages manually.  See:

- [Why is the MacTeX distribution so large? Is there anything smaller for OS X?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/974/2693)

It's possible to install the BasicTeX version of MacTeX, in which case you would need to install some packages yourself.

ProTeXt is a MikTeX distribution, and MikTeX installs packages on the fly, i.e., it installs a base distribution and packages get installed automatically. MikTeX support for Mac is very new, and most Mac users I know use MacTeX. It's a single download and you never have to worry about missing packages.