# LaTeX installation: latex not playing nice (at all)

Tags: installing, mactex

So i've been trying for a long, long time to install and use latex on my mac. I started, about a year ago, by installing MacTeX: it didn't work then. I was given a sample file by a colleague and the file wouldn't compile with Pdflatex on texworks. I mailed the file to a friend and it worked perfectly. So i uninstalled all my tex stuff and reinstalled it again.

I saw that an option on my settings that says TeX distribution switched from 2012 (Universal) to 2013 (Intel). Yet, the same problem arises, and I can't compile anything. I get this error in my latest try:

```
2014-01-29 22:54:58.845 LaTeXiT[343:507] 10.4-style
NSNumberFormatter method called on a 10.0-style formatter, which doesn't work.
Break on _NSNumberFormatter_Log_New_Methods_On_Old_Formatters to debug.
This message will only be logged once.
```

Any insight?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Dear Close Voters: Please leave a Close comment Why ? and What improvement will make it a focused Q, make an effort with a possible edit to improve it ? atleast for new users.

Comment: One needs two items installed to get started on LaTeX 1)TeX distribution i.e [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/) 2) LaTeX Editor probably with a simple one [TeXshop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/texshop.html) . Please Follow http://www.tug.org/twg/mactex/texonmacosx.html, http://www.ctan.org/starter  and see [I want to start using LaTeX on Mac OS X. Where do I start?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220/i-want-to-start-using-latex-on-mac-os-x-where-do-i-start)

Comment: If you have MacTeX installed, try opening a command terminal and typing the command `latex -v`; if all is well, it should return some coherent information about pdfTeX and so forth.  If it seems good, then try the command `latex small2e` (or `pdflatex small2e`); it should create a viewable file called `small2e.dvi` (or `small2e.pdf` if you used `pdflatex`).  If either of those steps fail, then there is a good chance something is wrong with your installation.  If both succeed, the problem(s) likely lie elsewhere.

Comment: This looks like an error from LaTeXit (a front-end), not from LaTeX itself. As @jon says, trying something at the Terminal to test the basic LaTeX system seems a good plan.

Comment: From the look of this error, it looks like you have a very old version of LaTeXit installed. Assuming you can compile a simple file with TeXShop or TeXWorks, this might solve the LaTeXit problem.

Comment: @jon all those worked -- compiling in the terminal hasn't been particularly challenging (guess I should've mentioned that) so I guess the problem is with TeXWorks. (LaTeXit also works)

Comment: LaTeXit works?  But the error you show seems to be LaTeXit related..?  (Note I neither use Macs nor LaTeXit.)